# Не инициализируеться больше 1 ListView

Tags: android, kotlin

У меня есть Фрагмент `MainFragment` в котором есть `ListView`. В `MainFragment` есть метод `getListView`, который возвращает этот ListView. В `MainActivity` я работаю с `ViewPager2`, в котором есть 7 страниц (monday, tuesday и.т.д). Для каждой страницы я инициализирую по одному `MainFragment`. Для управления над `ListView` фрагментов я использую класс `ListViewController`, которому передаю каждый фрагмент (делаю я это в методе `onPageScrolled` `viewPager`а в `onCreate`). Но вот в чем проблема: в самом классе `ListViewController` инициализируется `ListView` лишь фрагмента `monFragment` при попытке инициализации остальных - вылет программы с ругательством

> E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
> Process: com.trayvor.lessons, PID: 18093
> kotlin.UninitializedPropertyAccessException: lateinit property listView has not been initialized
> at com.trayvor.lessons.MainFragment.getListView(MainFragment.kt:24)
> at com.trayvor.lessons.ListViewController.(ListViewController.kt:21)
> at com.trayvor.lessons.MainActivity$onCreate$1.onPageScrolled(MainActivity.kt:51)

Код с комментариями:

MainActivity.kt :

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
private lateinit var lvController: ListViewController

private lateinit var manager:FragmentManager

private lateinit var viewPager:ViewPager2
private lateinit var pagerAdapter:FragmentStateAdapter

private lateinit var monFragment:MainFragment
private lateinit var tueFragment:MainFragment
private lateinit var wedFragment:MainFragment
private lateinit var thuFragment:MainFragment
private lateinit var friFragment:MainFragment
private lateinit var satFragment:MainFragment
private lateinit var sunFragment:MainFragment


override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

    monFragment = MainFragment()
    tueFragment = MainFragment()
    wedFragment = MainFragment()
    thuFragment = MainFragment()
    friFragment = MainFragment()
    satFragment = MainFragment()
    sunFragment = MainFragment()

    viewPager = findViewById(R.id.viewPager)
    manager = supportFragmentManager
    pagerAdapter = ScreenSlidePagerAdapter(this)
    viewPager.adapter = pagerAdapter


    viewPager.registerOnPageChangeCallback(object : ViewPager2.OnPageChangeCallback(){
        override fun onPageScrolled(position: Int, positionOffset: Float, positionOffsetPixels: Int) {
            super.onPageScrolled(position, positionOffset, positionOffsetPixels)
            lvController = ListViewController(monFragment, tueFragment, wedFragment, thuFragment, friFragment, satFragment, sunFragment, baseContext)
        }
    })
} //Далее PagerAdapter, который здесь роли не играет
```

MainFragment.kt :

```
class MainFragment() : Fragment() {

private lateinit var listView:ListView
private lateinit var row:View

override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
                          savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
    row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container,false)
    listView = row.findViewById(R.id.listView)
    return row
}

fun getListView():ListView{
    return listView
}}
```

ListViewController.kt :

```
class ListViewController(monFragment:MainFragment, tueFragment:MainFragment, wedFragment:MainFragment, thuFragment:MainFragment, friFragment:MainFragment, satFragment:MainFragment, sunFragment:MainFragment, context: Context) {

init {
    var monListView:ListView
    var tueListView:ListView
    var wedListView:ListView
    var thuListView:ListView
    var friListView:ListView
    var satListView:ListView
    var sunListView:ListView

    monListView = monFragment.getListView() //Все ок
    tueListView = tueFragment.getListView() //КРАШ
    wedListView = wedFragment.getListView() //КРАШ
    thuListView = thuFragment.getListView() //КРАШ
    friListView = friFragment.getListView() //КРАШ
    satListView = satFragment.getListView() //КРАШ
    sunListView = sunFragment.getListView() //КРАШ
}}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

listView в MainFragment инициализируется когда view будет создано. В активити запрашиваются сразу все экземпляры listview из всех фрагментов. А так как отображается (скорее всего) только один экземпляр MainFragment (напр., moday), то остальные не отрисованы и соответственно их listView не инициализированы.

Comment: Верно, стоит заметить, что viewPager все же прогружает следующую страницу и держит в памяти предыдущую (по умолчанию). Быстрым решением будет `setOffscreenPageLimit(N-1)` где N - колличество страниц (7). Это избыточно. Делегируйте работу каждому фрагменту.